# How to edit label_submit styling?

Tags: posts, functions, comments-template

This is going to sound like an easy fix, but I am looking to style my submit comment button on my comment form. Currently the code in the $args = array looks like this:

`'label_submit'          => __( 'Post Comment' ),`

I am wondering how to apply styling to this button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target your submit button in css like this. This will look for a input element with `type="sunmit"` in container id `respond`. So make sure your container id is `respond` otherwise change it too.

```
#respond input[type=submit] {
    /* your styles */
}
```

Comment: How would I apply a container ID to this button though? That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: You don't need to apply container to button only. You must have id on `<form>` or on `<div>` wrapped around the form. Right? you can use that id too.